# Problems with animating SVG in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, animation, svg

can You help mi with that... i've got SVG and it's working fine in Chrome and other but of course there are problems with IE.
Is there any options to make it work with IE (as I know there aren't)? So maybe You can show an option for code that recognize user browser and when it's Chrome, Firefox or Safari it will run animated svg and if it's IE it will show other image.
I've tried with `<comment>` but i can't make it working...
Thx for any help...

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 193" enable-background="new 0 0 374 193">
<style>


#linia {
  animation: draw 7s ease ;
  stroke-dasharray: 1500;
}
@keyframes draw {
  0% {stroke-dashoffset: 1500}
  100% {stroke-dashoffset: 0}
}
</style>

 <path id="linia" d="M620.6,157.9c3.9,0,4.8,1.8,4.4,4.6l-3.6,29.4c-1.8,14.1-11.3,28.1-43,28.1c-27.9,0-37.9-12-37.9-25&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;c0-1.1,0.2-3,0.3-4.4l6.9-56.8c1.6-14.1,11.3-28.1,43-28.1c27.9,0,37.9,12,37.9,25.1c0,1-0.2,2.6-0.3,4.4l-0.5,4.4&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;c-0.3,3.4-1.8,4.9-5.3,4.9h-16.9c-3.4,0-4.6-2-4.1-4.9l0.2-1.1c0.2-1.1,0.2-2,0.2-2.6c0-5.4-4.8-8-12.3-8&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;c-7.9,0-14.3,3.1-15.3,10.7l-5.9,47.3c-0.2,1.1-0.3,2.5-0.3,3.3c0,6.1,4.6,8.7,12.5,8.7c8.9,0,14.3-3.1,15.1-10.7l0.8-7.1H583&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;c-3.4,0-4.8-1.5-4.3-4.8l1.6-12.8c0.3-3.4,2-4.6,5.4-4.6H620.6z" fill="none" stroke="#CF0a2c" stroke-width="1" stroke-miterlimit="10">
  <animate id="1" attributeName="fill" from="#fff" to="#CF0A2C" begin="2s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
 </path>

 
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

SMIL animation, the type that uses the `<animate>` element, is not supported by IE or Edge.  You could try the [FakeSmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/) polyfill.

Comment: Unfortunately FakeSmile doesn't work with <stroke-dasharray>... Tried in every way and get the answer that it won't work. Maybe someone knows the solution based on idea that animated svg code is seen by Chrome etc and static version by Explorer?

Comment: SInce IE doesn't support animation of SVG elements, you will always see a static image in IE. :)

Comment: The SMIL version, of your original example above, would be something [like ths](https://jsfiddle.net/4jz1x4t5/).

Comment: Yes, it's working fine. In IE it's static and in other browser animation is quite nice.

Comment: of course.... thank You Paul for providing an simple solution... Your answer gave me that clue... Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you right Paul, but because fading in background i IE i'm seeing just outlined image... :-( maybe if I will animate fill 2 times (first - very fast, like 0.1 sec from red bo white and then stroke-dasharray effect, and at the end again fading in fill from white to red but longer) i would get what I need... maybe it's not the best solution...Like fakeSmile - but it should work ;-)
Also it need change of initial filling.

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 193" enable-background="new 0 0 374 193">
<style>


#linia {
  animation: draw 7s ease ;
  stroke-dasharray: 1500;
}
@keyframes draw {
  0% {stroke-dashoffset: 1500}
  100% {stroke-dashoffset: 0}
}
</style>

 <path id="linia" d="M620.6,157.9c3.9,0,4.8,1.8,4.4,4.6l-3.6,29.4c-1.8,14.1-11.3,28.1-43,28.1c-27.9,0-37.9-12-37.9-25&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;c0-1.1,0.2-3,0.3-4.4l6.9-56.8c1.6-14.1,11.3-28.1,43-28.1c27.9,0,37.9,12,37.9,25.1c0,1-0.2,2.6-0.3,4.4l-0.5,4.4&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;c-0.3,3.4-1.8,4.9-5.3,4.9h-16.9c-3.4,0-4.6-2-4.1-4.9l0.2-1.1c0.2-1.1,0.2-2,0.2-2.6c0-5.4-4.8-8-12.3-8&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;c-7.9,0-14.3,3.1-15.3,10.7l-5.9,47.3c-0.2,1.1-0.3,2.5-0.3,3.3c0,6.1,4.6,8.7,12.5,8.7c8.9,0,14.3-3.1,15.1-10.7l0.8-7.1H583&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;&#9;c-3.4,0-4.8-1.5-4.3-4.8l1.6-12.8c0.3-3.4,2-4.6,5.4-4.6H620.6z" fill="#CF0A2C" stroke="#CF0a2c" stroke-width="1" stroke-miterlimit="10">
    <animate id="1" attributeName="fill" from="#CF0A2C" to="#fff" begin="0s" dur="0.01s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
    <animate id="2" attributeName="fill" from="#fff" to="#CF0A2C" begin="2s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
 </path>


</svg>
```